# How to return MAX and MIN of a value from a table?

Tags: sql, max, min

I want to get the last cost with latest costing date and minimum cost for products.

When I use the query below, it is giving me the Max Date and Min Cost for each column. Please see the screenshots below.

```
SELECT MAX(CostingDate) AS LatestDate,
MIN(Cost) AS MinPrice,
OutletCode,
ProductID  
FROM AccountsCosting
WHERE OutletCode = 'C&T01'
GROUP BY OutletCode, ProductID
```

Result:

[image]

E.g - for productID: `200006`

```
SELECT * FROM AccountsCosting
WHERE ProductID = 200006 AND OutletCode = 'C&T01'
ORDER BY CostingDate DESC
```

[image]

What I want is the last costing date with the minimum cost (the one that I highlighted with red color). Even if the purchase date is the same `2013-03-20`, it should return the minimum cost.

[image]

How can I edit my query to get the result? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You've made this question very confusing, so you want to only bring out the highlighted row?

Comment: Yeah! I want to get the cost of the latest costing date. The more I explain, the more it's getting confused.

Comment: Ok, by the sounds of things you will want to use the SELECT TOP 1 clause. I will post an answer now for you and see if it's the result your looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to get the Latest Date then you can find the minimum cost for them. e.g.

```
 select 
    a.OutletCode, 
    a.ProductID,
     LatestDate,
    MIN(Cost) AS MinPrice

from

    (
    SELECT MAX(CostingDate) AS LatestDate,
    OutletCode,
    ProductID  
    FROM AccountsCosting
    WHERE OutletCode = 'C&T01'
    GROUP BY OutletCode, ProductID
    ) a
    left join 
    FROM AccountsCosting b
    on
    a.OutletCode=b.OutletCode
    and a.ProductID=b.ProductID  
    and a.LatestDate=b.CostingDate

    group by a.OutletCode, a.ProductID, LatestDate
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. It was really difficult to explain what I want to do without showing the query that I have. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you want the minimum cost for the latest date?!

Try this:

```
SELECT CostingDate AS LatestDate,
Cost AS MinPrice,
OutletCode,
ProductID  
FROM AccountsCosting
WHERE OutletCode = 'C&T01'
and CostingDate in (SELECT MAX(CostingDate) as CostingDate FROM AccountsCosting WHERE OutletCode = 'C&T01')
and Cost in (SELECT MIN(Cost) as Cost FROM AccountsCosting WHERE OutletCode = 'C&T01' and CostingDate in (SELECT MAX(CostingDate) as CostingDate FROM AccountsCosting WHERE OutletCode = 'C&T01'))
GROUP BY OutletCode, ProductID;
```

Comment: It returned only one row with latest costing date and cost among all the records in my table because of using `IN` in `WHERE` statement. Anyway, I really appreciate your help! +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to do 2 queries for the MAX & MIN, then Join them together to get your single row. I'd either use temp tables or CTE's, e.g.

```
WITH CTE_Max AS
(SELECT MAX(costingDate) as latestDate,
 Oultletcode,
ProductID
FROM AccountsCosting
GROUP BY OutletCode, ProductID),

CTE_Min AS
(SELECT MIN(cost) as MinPrice,
Oultletcode,
ProductID
FROM AccountsCosting
GROUP BY OutletCode, ProductID)

SELECT * FROM CTE_Max 
JOIN CTE_Min
ON CTE_Max.outletCode=CTE_Min.outletCode
AND CTE_Max.productID=CTE_Min.productID
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `SQL Server 2005` and after you can use `CTE` and `RANK() OVER()`

```
;WITH AccountCostingForOutletCode AS  (
    SELECT OutletCode, ProductID, CostingDate, Cost, 
       RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY OutletCode, ProductID ORDER BY Cost, CostingDate DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM AccountsCosting
    WHERE OutletCode = 'C&T01'
)
SELECT TOP 1 OutletCode, ProductID, CostingDate, Cost, Rnk
FROM AccountCostingForOutletCode
ORDER BY Rnk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something if you only wish to show output

```sql
SELECT ProductName,Max(price) as MxP, '-' as minP from products 
UNION
SELECT ProductName,'-' as MxP , Min(price) as minP from products
```